# Constructing the whole sql and running it using preparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I have a use case in which I am trying to create the whole sql based on the user`s ip to the api.

EG: user hits the api with the format `/what/table/field/field_value?name=value1`

```
public static Result getRows(String what, String table, String field, String field_value, String more_where_clause) throws SQLException {
    //more_where_clause will have as many condition for where clause

          String sql = String.format("select ? from ? where ?=?");

          if (!where.equals("")) {
              sql += String.format(" and ?");
          }
          ResultSet rs = targetDB.query(sql, what, table, field, field_value, more_where_clause);



public <T extends Comparable<T>>ResultSet query(String sql, T... args) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            preparedStatement.setObject(i + 1, args[i]);
        }
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs;
}
```

But when I query it using say :

```
/name/user_table/first_name/john?last_name=doe
```

I get a sql string like

```
select 'name' from 'user_table' where 'first_name'='john' and 'last_name=doe'
as             preparedStatement.setObject(i + 1, args[i]);
```

infers it as String.

What is a better way to do this and also avoid sql injection. 
EDIT :
Also apart from parameterizing the where clause part, what other extra checks can I do? How do I take care of the more_where_clause where user can enter more things to the where condition.

Comment: You cannot avoid SQL injection if you basically let the user inject _everything_, including table names (which you cannot have as bind variables and need to concatenate into the query literal). Normally, you just let the user input the column _values_, which you can then safely sanitize through a prepared statement.

Comment: So I cannot  bind it bcoz of the same reason i.e. 'name' from 'user_table' coz of the extra '' quotes. Right?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: You cannot bind because table or column names cannot be variables; only column values can.

Comment: Oh ok. Shouldn`t have missed that. I have a regex check on the table and column though, but that`s not a fullproof approach ever.

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind names (field, table, etc.), just values.

Based on security principles you can define a "white-list" regular expression to check name conformity with your restriction (ie allowing only `[A-ZaZ0-9_-]+`)

Poorer solution is to define a "black-list" on which you forbid double-quotes (`"`) and escape sequences (if dealing with multiple RDBMS engine, it can be a pain) and then put all names between double-quotes. Be aware of case-sentivity when using double-quotes.

You can also check [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) librairies. I know they offer APIs to deal with HTML, CSS, JavaScript & HTTP injections. May be they also define API to deal with generated SQL.

Ultimately you can also build/query database metadata and match object names against provided ones. Which in this case you can rely on value binding. In this case don't forget to use value returned from metadata and to enclosed them in double-quotes on generated SQL.

Comment: Is this a good soln https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html  although i have heard otherwise.

Comment: Caution, `StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql` only deal with values not names.

Comment: statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MOVIES WHERE TITLE='" + 
   StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql("McHale's Navy") + 
   "'");  if I do statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MOVIES WHERE StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql("TITLE")='" + 
   StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql("McHale's Navy") + 
   "'");  that would fail?

Comment: But ya this anyways doesn`t prevent me from adding a DROP statement to the where clause. So.